# How to do Scope=RecursiveAll with Linq To Sharepoit

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, linq

I have the following CAML query:

caml = string.Format("{0}", code);

query = new SPQuery { Query = caml, ViewAttributes = "Scope = \"RecursiveAll\"" };

This query search in a document library a list of items sprawl in the subfolders.
I would like to translate it in LinqToSP and I do that:

var list = dc.GetList("MyDocs");
list.ScopeToFolder(string.Empty, true);
var items = list
            .Where(s => s.Code.Id.Equals(item.Id));

but in this way I don't get any item.
Why?
Tnx

Comment: caml = string.Format("<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"LookupToMyCode\" LookupId=\"TRUE\" /><Value Type=\"Lookup\">{0}</Value></Eq></Where>", code);

Answer (score 1):

You need to query results of ScopeToFolder call. And first parameter shoul contain list url, not empty string.